# Python - How do I shell-scape a variable?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pycharm

I need to run the following shell script from python:

```
AliasScript = "osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to make alias at \
POSIX file \"" + dirAlbumName + "\" as alias to \
POSIX file \"" + dirName + "\" as alias'"

os.system(AliasScript + "&> /dev/null")
```

It only works if the `dirAlbumName` and/or `dirName` variables don't contain any metacharacters (or are they called special characters?), such as `\`, `'`, or `"`. For example, if `dirName` = `/\/\/\ !@#$%^&*()|?"'"" /\?\/` I get a syntax error.

How do I shell-escape these variables? I tried using shlex based on what I read from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), but I can't get it to work. For example, I tried `shlex.quote(dirName)` but that doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, this code will be run hundreds of times inside a loop with different values for `dirName` and `dirAlbumName`, so I can't just manually escape them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use python string formatting to pass exactly what you want, for example you'd need to do the following:

```py
dirAlbumName=r"jim&bo"
dirName=r"jon smith"
AliasScriptTemplate = r"osascript -e 'tell application \"{0}\" to make alias at \
POSIX file \"{1}\" as alias to \
POSIX file \"{2}\" as alias'"
AliasScript = AliasScriptTemplate.format("Finder",dirAlbumName,dirName)
AliasScript += r'&> /dev/null'
os.system(AliasScript)
```

the key here is that the `r` prefixing the strings means python wont "do" anything to the string, but keep it exactly as is. more details here https://www.linode.com/docs/development/python/string-manipulation-python-3/

Note that python's subprocess module is great for running scripts and will allow you much better control over what you're doing, including redirecting stderr and stdout to files/variables/, see explanation here https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94463/subprocess.run

Comment: I just tried that, and I got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pschorn/PycharmProjects/SpotifyIndex/SpotlightIndex.py", line 178, in <module>
    show_tracks(tracks)
  File "/Users/pschorn/PycharmProjects/SpotifyIndex/SpotlightIndex.py", line 122, in show_tracks
    AliasScript.append(r'&> /dev/null')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: I just added something to my question as well.

Comment: Is there a parenthesis missing in the second to last line of your code?

Comment: There’s an extra one at the end of the second to last line, fixed. Thx

Comment: I still can't get it work. Now, nothing happens if `dirAlbumName` contains special characters

Comment: @PeterSchorn when i run this locally i get the following string out (not on mac so can't debug that part)
```>>> print(AliasScript)
osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to make alias at \
POSIX file \"jim&bo\" as alias to \
POSIX file \"jon smith\" as alias'&> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `shlex.quote` module to escape your `dirAlnumName` and `dirName`. I'm not familiar with the scripting language you're using but here's what happens here.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> dirname="""/\/\/\ !@#$%^&*()|?"'"" /\?\/"""
>>> print(shlex.quote(dirname))
'/\/\/\ !@#$%^&*()|?"'"'"'"" /\?\/'
>>> print (dirname)
/\/\/\ !@#$%^&*()|?"'"" /\?\/
>>>
```

and here is a live example

```
>>> fname = "\name"
>>> import os
>>> os.system("touch " +fname)
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
sh: 2: ame: not found
32512
>>> import shlex
>>> os.system("touch " +shlex.quote(fname))
0
```

A safer approach is to use the `subprocess` module and avoid the shell altogether.e.g.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['touch', '\name'])
>>> _.wait()
0
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use the subprocess module for the code above in my question? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the language that you've written your script in.

Comment: It's apple script. However, I've given up on this problem. I'll just make sure that there aren't any special characters in the variables.

Comment: The issue is that `os.system` relies on the shell to parse the command into the words (e.g. `ls -l` into `ls` and `-l`). That will bring up the question of quoting etc. If you split the command into words by yourself, the shell is not involved and the quoting problem won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your issue. I have created a folder named "$#$%@@". You need to pass an escape character whenever '#' appears in it.
For example:

```
/path/to/folder/$\#$%@@
```